# php вывод значений объекта массива

Tags: php, json

С помощью var_dump($q[0]) выводиться

```
object(Entity\Responses\StatusesResponse)#37 (5) {
  ["code":protected]=>
  string(29) "ACCEPTED_AT"
  ["name":protected]=>
  string(45) "Принят"
  ["reason_code":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

как мне с помощью echo вывести только "ACCEPTED_AT" ?

Comment: Наверное для этого должен быть какой-то геттер. Вы бы не хотели привести немного больше деталей? Что это за фреймворк/библиотека?

Comment: Посмотрите, какие методы есть у данного StatusesResonse, можно через reflectionApi, можно через get_class_methods, а так же, вам должна подсказать IDE, если написать что-то вроде: `/** @var StatusesResponse $status */ $status = $q[0]; $status->{тут появится контекстное меню с списком методов}` и далее, велика веротяность, что для оного свойства будет getter (т.е. метод получения значения данного свойства). Ну и по итогу, получится что-то вроде: `echo $q[0]->getCode()`.

Comment: мой IDE notepad, он не подсказывает )
Благодарю, за подсказку, нашел в файле $q[0]->getCode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getter нашлись в файле по пути  Entity\Responses\StatusesResponse

```
$q[0]->getCode()
```